# I like to sing lyrics as I come up with them. What is this called?

Tags: songwriting, lyrics

As I write lyrics, I just start singing & turn them into full verses/choruses.

1. What is this called? melody?
2. What is my next step into turning them into pop songs?
   Do i turn each syllable into music notes? Do i make a melody to accompany them or chords?

Comment: I call it “singing lyrics as you come up with them”.

Comment: @ToddWilcox or "composition."  Mr. Lo: I find myself wondering what _you_ think is lacking in your "full verses/choruses" that marks them as not pop songs.  If you can express that it will help us understand how to advise you.  Maybe your next step is in fact to identify what's missing.

Comment: I think we need some more explanation. If you're singing, you *do* have a melody, but the questions about "turn each syllable into music notes" and "do I make a melody" sounds like maybe you haven't already been making music? And you seem to have two questions here, one asking for more information about what you already do, and one about what to do next. I suggest starting a second question and giving both more detail.

Comment: haha Mr Wilcox!!  Andy/phoog >  Good replies, thank you much. I am a rookie at music and I suck explaining things. So here is my example:  I got fired one day, and lost my girlfriend, so I felt super crappy.   I started motivating myself to stop being so weak by singing made up lyrics. Using my DAW, I want to put music to it but I don't know where to start. Is what I am singing already the melody part? Don't laugh but here is my nonsense so far.  https://www.youtube.com/@lepoz2023/videos   Besides the bad quality & bad singing, what do i need to make these songs sound correct/less sucky?

Comment: It sounds like what you'd really like is songwriting advice. The best place for that is the [chat rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=music.stackexchange.com) that are associated with this Stack Exchange; there's even one called "The Auditorium" just for sharing your work and getting feedback. These kinds of questions are too broad to make good "official" *questions* on Stack Exchange; you can see [the topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You need 20 reputation to participate in the chat rooms, but it can be earned pretty quickly.

Comment: Also: there isn't a lot that you "have" to do when making music. Don't worry too much about it! You can learn more about music terminology, and find sources of general advice, but you're already doing the most important thing: actually *making* the music. Without that, advice and knowledge do nothing.

Comment: SWEET... Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, Andy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, it's called [extemporisation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/extemporization), which is similar to [improvisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_improvisation), though many people would just call it [jamming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jam_session) [usually involving multiple musicians], [riffing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riff), or just 'making it up as you go along' ;)

If you have no scoring or other recognisable musical skills, your next step is to record it as audio so you can refer back to it later.
After that you're into the whole wide world of musical performance and composition, which would require several books or many years with a teacher to even begin to answer.

Comment: Great answer! You are correct, I have no skills. And what you said is exactly what I did by recording it. Now I am stuck not knowing what to do next to make it sound like a real song. Suggestions? I can't even figure out what genre my nonsense is..  https://www.youtube.com/@lepoz2023/videos

Answer (score 0):

If you sing the words to notes, you already have the *melody*. Usually one note per syllable, but that note needn't be a different note for each.

Next move is to *harmonise* that melody, with chords that fit (obviously!), and make the whole lot into lines, verses and choruses.

Comment: "with chords that fit": where "fit" is highly subjective.

Comment: @phoog - well, it wouldn't sound good with chords that don't fit. Subjective, obviously, obvious, subjectively.

Comment: I usually do it the other way around - let the melody condense around the chords I'm playing. But everyone's creative process is different, so do what works for you.

Comment: So i guess I need to now learn what key I am in and what scale to use so that I can translate the lyrics into notes??? Then that will be the melody? Or do I still need an accompanying melody? I put the youtube link in the other answers. If all you heard was what I was singing, what would you do next?  Thank you all for your patience.

Comment: @Divizna - it can (and does) work both ways, and often simultaneously.

Comment: Having listened (briefly) to your offerings, there's already words, backing, and a sort of tune. That all constitutes a 'song'. What more do you need?

Comment: @Tim ok thanks. I just thought it sounded incomplete.